# Why IManageApiKeys dependency is not resolved with ServiceStack ApiKeyAuthProvider?

Tags: servicestack

Here is my **auth config**

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
   new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) { RequireSecureConnection = false, InitSchema = true},
   new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings)
   })
   {
      IncludeRegistrationService = true,

   });
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(dbFactory));
   container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

When I try to resolve dependency of IManageApiKeys in service it throws exception **Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.Auth.OrmLiteAuthRepository' to type 'ServiceStack.Auth.IManageApiKeys**

```
var apiRepo = (IManageApiKeys)base.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>();
```

I am not able to figure out how to resolve dependency of IManageApiKeys and it doesn't create ApiKey table through InitSchema() however UserAuth, UserAuthDetails and UserAuthRole are created.

Comment: I am using ServiceStack Version 4.0.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OrmLiteAuthRepository does implement IManageApiKeys](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7625198e0010ef85ceb8737d21bfbaf50c5e5e02/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs#L160) so I'm assuming that your `OrmLiteAuthRepository` that's in the **ServiceStack.Server** NuGet package isn't the same version as **ServiceStack** NuGet package.

Check your `/packages` folder and make sure that each ServiceStack dependency references the same version number, if there's different versions upgrade each project so they're all referencing the same version.